# Close sideform on opening of another sideform

Tags: reactjs

I want to close a sideform when we click on another sideform open button. How is it possible?
My issue is already opened sideform is hiding the newly opened sideform

Comment: what are you talking about?

Comment: Please, share a reproducible example of your code

Comment: Please provide more details

Answer (score 1):

you will need to send your state and setState function between your components using props, or if you have a large-scale project you will need a state management system like context API or redux, you can easily set the state of your side bar to false whenever the other button has been clicked.

see the docs for context API created by react itself.
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html